# Insert layers on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Is there a simple way to insert layers (a feature of Visual Studio 2005) in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: I don't recall layers. Are you sure they are a VS2005 feature? Can you post a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DIV from the HTML category within the Toolbox, select this new DIV, then use **Format** -> **Set Position** -> **Absolute**.